# SQL query returning an extra record

Tags: sql

I've tried both right and inner join, either I end up with an extra record or not record at all. Please suggest what to fix in this query.

Table structure 
Event -> Day -> Session
session_attendee

```
SELECT session.id,
(SELECT count(*) from event e INNER JOIN day AS d ON e.id = d.event_id INNER JOIN session AS s ON d.id = s.day_id WHERE e.id = event.id AND d.id = day.id) AS total,
day.date, session.name, session.start, session.end, session.room,
(SELECT COUNT(distinct attendee_id) FROM session s LEFT JOIN session_attendee AS sa ON s.id = sa.session_id WHERE s.id = session.id) AS attendees
FROM event
LEFT JOIN day ON event.id = day.event_id
LEFT JOIN session ON day.id = session.day_id
LEFT JOIN session_attendee ON session.id = session_attendee.session_id
WHERE event.id = 12
GROUP BY session.id
ORDER BY day.date, session.start, event.name;
```

Resultset

```
[
{
"id": 9,
"total": 1,
"date": "2015-05-12T04:00:00.000Z",
"name": "test",
"start": "00:55:00",
"end": "00:55:00",
"room": "abc",
"attendees": 0
},
{
"id": null,
"total": 0,
"date": "2015-05-13T04:00:00.000Z",
"name": null,
"start": null,
"end": null,
"room": null,
"attendees": 0
}
]
```

Comment: Because one or more of LEFT JOINED tables has record with null data with same join conditions

Answer (score 0):

Just try it on postgresql, you sql query will fail, because it's wrong.
You are trying to select fields without an aggregate function and why do you not have a `GROUP BY`?

But the main reason why it is an incorrect query, is that you must change it to something like this:

```
WHERE session.id in (
SELECT 
    session.id
    FROM
    event
        LEFT JOIN
    day ON event.id = day.event_id
        LEFT JOIN
    session ON day.id = session.day_id
    WHERE
    event.id = 12
```